# Why is this alert not executing in the if-statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, while-loop

This program should display an alert `Found it` on the 4th iteration

```
var animals = ["horse", "ox", "cow", "pig", "duck"];  
var i = 0;  
while (i < animals.length) {  
  if (animals.slice(i, i + 1) === "pig") {  
      alert("Found it");  
      break;  
  }  
 i++;  
}
```

Comment: Debugging code step by step helps to solve errors.

Comment: If you want to check if an element is present in array use `indexOf`, `animals.indexOf('pig') > -1`

Answer (score 2):

`animals.slice` returns an array while you're comparing it to the string. Try with:

```
if (animals[i] === "pig") {}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var animals=["horse", "ox", "cow", "pig", "duck"];  
var i = 0;  
while (i < animals.length) {  
  if (animals[i] = "pig") {  
      alert("Found it");  
      break;  
  }  
 i++;  
}
```

This will solve your problem. Don't use [slice](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) not needed in your code.